# Sharepoint Picture Library with albums

Tags: sharepoint

I want to store number of photo album in SharePoint Picture library, I can create different folder and store picture to respected folder. Is it possible to change folder picture and make it thumbnail size  so it look like album. Or is there any better solution for this

Regards,

Comment: Hello Nikhil! Do you have tried anything already? Stackoverflow is a Q&A site for specific programming questions. Showing some code helps us to solve the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Icon image for folders in the actual root of your website directory, but this will affect all folders on your website.
There does not appear to be a way to specify a specific icon for a folder; they all utilise the same file globally.

I honestly think you would be better off avoiding doing this. If it's possible (I can't categorically say no because I'm not omnipotent) it would be very hackish, as there is no methods built into Sharepoint, and take a lot of effort for very small aesthetic benefit.